# Last button in JFrame is set as background?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

```
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 


public class Test extends JFrame { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public Test() { 
        super("A test"); 
        setSize(360,300);//Size of JFrame 
        setResizable(false); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true);//Sets if its visible. 

        JButton num1 = new JButton("1");//Set the JButton name 
        JButton num2 = new JButton("2"); 
        JButton num3 = new JButton("3"); 

        num1.setBounds(80,70,50,50); 
        num2.setBounds(130,70,50,50); 
        num3.setBounds(180,70,50,50); 

        add(num1); 
        add(num2); 
        add(num3); 
    } 
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        new Test().setVisible(true); 
    } 
}
```

Here the num3 button is set as the background, I want the buttons to be aligned. This might be a trivial mistake I'm not sure as I've just started working with JFrame. Thank you.

[image: button3]

Comment: Do not set bounds. Use an appropriate layout manager. If you're looking to align buttons horizontally, use `FlowLayout`.

Comment: setLayout(null) could do the trick, but i would not reccomend that, it's good for starting with few components, but unusable for acctuals projects. Read some LayoutManager tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

Basically, there are three parts that are causing this problems...

1. `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default. This means that only the last component add to any one of the five available layout positions will be managed
2. You call `setVisible(true)` before adding anything to the frame
3. You call `setBounds` on the buttons.

Because the components are generally painted in z-order (in FIFO order generally) and because of the optimisation in the code, the last button is been controlled by the `BorderLayout` of the frame, but the other two maintain the bounds you set before

Really interesting problem

### Solution(s)

1. Use an appropriate layout manager, maybe a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout`
2. Call `setVisible` last where ever possible

Check out [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for details

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Layout Manager. Please check the code below.

i use another JPanel to put all the buttons. i set the panel as it will have 1 row and 3 columns objects.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Test extends JFrame { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 


JPanel buttonPanel;

public Test() { 
    super("A test"); 
    setSize(360,300);//Size of JFrame 
    setResizable(false); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setVisible(true);//Sets if its visible. 
    setLayout(null);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    buttonPanel.setBounds(80, 70, 150, 50);
    JButton num1 = new JButton("1");//Set the JButton name 
    JButton num2 = new JButton("2"); 
    JButton num3 = new JButton("3"); 

    buttonPanel.add(num1); 
    buttonPanel.add(num2); 
    buttonPanel.add(num3); 

    add(buttonPanel);
} 


 public static void main (String[] args) { 
        new Test().setVisible(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: this is a quick answer that suitable for your code, but generally i don't use setLayout(null).

Answer (score 0):

Well, never use raw placing and no Layout Manager.
[This is your Bible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

You can do that with some Layout tricks. For example this one:

First of all import the Layout classes.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
```

Make the frame a BorderLayout frame by copying this in the constructor of it.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Then make another JPanel and make it a GridLayout JPanel:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
panel.add(num1);
panel.add(num2);
panel.add(num3);
```

Arguments 1 and 3 mean "use exactly 1 row and 3 columns to place the widgets in this JPanel".

Finally add the last panel at the center of the frame:

```
add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This way you won't deal with dimensions or precise spots and still do what you want...

(to test it copy all the code in "Test" constructor)